# Encountered weird sawtooth when drawing rounded corner images on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, quartz-2d

I'm trying to create thumbnail images with rounded corners and with a bar at the bottom of the image on iOS.

And I have the following code:

```
extension UIImage {
  func thumbnails(with options: SomeDrawingOptions) -> UIImage? {
    // ...

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, false, 0)
    defer {
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    UIColor.white.setFill()
    context.fill(targetRect)

    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect, cornerRadius: 8).addClip()

    // Drawing image
    draw(in: targetRect)

    // Drawing a transparent mask
    UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).setFill()
    context.fill(targetRect)

    // Drawing bar
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    context.fill(someBarRect)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Finally I've got an image with sharp rounded corners just like those in the following snapshot.

[image: Sharp Rounded Corners]

Any advise to eliminate the sawtooth of rounded corners?

======= Solution added ======

Thanks the answer for @wj2061, the problem solved. And here is the code:

```
extension UIImage {
  func thumbnails(with options: SomeDrawingOptions) -> UIImage? {
    // ...

    let targetRect = options.targetRect
    let clippedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect, cornerRadius: 8)

    func makeImage() -> UIImage? {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, false, 0)
      defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

      draw(in: targetRect)

      // Drawing a transparent mask
      UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).setFill()
      context.fill(targetRect)

      // Drawing bar
      UIColor.white.setFill()
      context.fill(someBarRect)

      return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Drawing image
    clippedPath.addClip()
    makeImage()?.draw(in: targetRect)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: @matt The rounded corners should not be seen when the bar color of the image is the same as the background color of the container view (in this case, it's the collection view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like this pitfall has something to do with `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect, cornerRadius: 8).addClip()`, and I try to add mask to image in step 1, add corner to image in step 2. The code is like this

```
extension UIImage {
func thumbnails() -> UIImage? {
    let targetRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 150)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, false, 0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect, cornerRadius: 8).addClip()

    let makedImage = self.makedImage()

    makedImage?.draw(in : targetRect)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}


func makedImage()->UIImage?{
    let targetRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 150)
    let someBarRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, false, 0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    draw(in : targetRect)


    // Drawing a transparent mask
    UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).setFill()
    context.fill(targetRect)

    // Drawing bar
    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1).setFill()
    context.fill(someBarRect)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 }
}
```

Comment: After restoring GState(), the bar will not be clipped, and the two rounded corners at the bottom disappeared.

Comment: It seems like `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext.clear()` is the method you are looking for. I also change the order or 'context.fill(targetRect)' , so that the image don't have an white top corner.

Comment: It actually worked. The sawtooth got eliminated. However, a bar with transparent color can not be painted on. Although I set a transparent color filled, the transparent effect can not be seen.

Comment: then you have to create your maskImage separately ,or use UIGraphicsPushContext().